# Why doesn't the built-in python help function display all the possible commands?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I was looking for a command that I could use to delete a specific element in an array. So I decided to use the built-in `help()` function.

```
help([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

The result of this was that I was able to find the `remove()` function but nowhere did it mention the `del` keyword, which turned out to be useful.

Are there any similar functions like `help()` that would also output keywords like `del`?

Comment: `help` is meant to display the `__docstring__` of a function. `del` is part of the syntax, it is not a function.

Comment: If you want information on something that `help` doesn't give, you could always look at the python documentation.

Comment: It's worth noting that `del some_list[index]` is implemented by `list.__delitem__`, which *is* documented by `help(list)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way, the answer to your question is inside your question. It is correct that `remove()` is in `help()` because the `help()` function displays functions built in to Python. However, `del` is not a function. It's a keyword. Keywords are part of the Python syntax, so information about those would only be in the documentation, or other online tutorials. It's not in the `help()` function for the same reason that `def`, `while`, and `if` aren't in the `help()` function. They're part of what makes the Python language, and `remove()` was added and is part of the main module that is included with all Python distributions.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me understand it.